# excel calc define range of cells

Tags: excel, openoffice-calc

I need a range definition shared by different cell formulas

I have an array of values:

starting with row 4:

```
v11;v12;v13;v14 ....
v21;v22;v23;v24 ....
v31;v32;v33;v34 ....
```

What I want to do is to define range of cells R4C1:R10C7
And use it in two different formulas. 
For example in row 1 i could put

```
A;           B               ; C
R4C1:R10C7;  MIN(ADDRESS(A1)); MAX(ADDRESS(A1));
```

Now if I change range definition in A1 both min and max should update automaticly.
The problem is that ADDRESS returns reference to only a single cell.
Is there a method to return range of cells?
Preferably working both in ms and libra office, wihtout python or

---

Works perfectly:

```
A;           B               ; C
A4:G10;  MIN(INDIRECT(A1)); MAX(INDIRECT(A1));
```

And for polish it is =MAKS(ADR.POŚR(A1))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need INDIRECT rather than ADDRESS:

```
=MIN(INDIRECT(A1))
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
INDIRECT(ADDRESS(A1))
```

and you should be ok